# Grafana couldn't display Kubernetes pod CPU and Memory usage, but it displays pod network and file system usage

Tags: kubernetes, grafana, kubernetes-pod

My kubernetes cluster contains 1 master and 2 minion nodes. I have deployed a sample stress-ng CPU intensive test for 10 minutes to get the CPU usage of nodes and kubernetes pods. I have used influx DB as datasource for Grafana. To visualize the CPU usage I have used Grafana. In Grafana for kubernetes nodes, I have no issues and I could get all graphs including CPU usage.

But for Kubernetes pods I couldn't get CPU usage and memory usage (it displays Network Error: undefined(undefined)) both for default `kube-system` pods as well as for my stress-ng application pod. I have attached Grafana screenshots for stress-ng pod and node. Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

stress-ng pod Grafana screenshot:

[image: stress-ng pod Grafana screenshot]

node grafana screenshot:

[image: node grafana screenshot]

Comment: What does kubectl get pods --all-namespaces show? Does it show your network protocol (weave etc..) running?

Comment: do you have these metrics in prometheus itself?

Comment: Hi @VKR I'm using influxDB instead of prometheus. Configuration files for heapster, grafana, influxDB are in my git repository. You can have a look https://github.com/rvamsi12345/k8sproject

Comment: Hi @ Aoradon. my network protocol is calico and it is running. (kube-system   calico-etcd-7svdl                         1/1       Running   0          10m,
kube-system   calico-kube-controllers-57d4b9ddd-tl2fh   1/1       Running   0          10m,
kube-system   calico-node-hmhml                         2/2       Running   0          10m,
kube-system   calico-node-j9lfs                         2/2       Running   1          10m,
kube-system   calico-node-mwnt4                         2/2       Running   0          10m)